# How should I go about transferring a csv file to a database using C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, csv

I have a particularly difficult task that I am trying to figure out, but just can't seem to wrap my head around. I have have been tasked with making a program that transfers data from a CSV file to a database (mysql). I have researched and have found and understand the `load data infile` method of doing this, however, every CSV file may be different from my database table, for example the data fields in my table may be `Land Price, Parcel no, and Locaton` to keep things simple. Now the files to be uploaded may look like this.

Example CSV file:

[image]

Example CSV file 2:
[image]

As you can see the pronlem lies in csv file 2 since the fields  are not only out of order but the names of the fields don't match the fields of my table. So how can I go about solving this problem of mapping the correct data from the CSV file to the correct field in my database table? I'm only looking for ideas and pseudo code type of answers. My initial idea is that I'd have to create a new table for each csv file but I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to google, the root problem you're dealing with is a data transform. It's a common task as a programmer.

There's two general ways to do this:
1 - you could stick with the loaddatainfile, create a new table for each CSV and then write a SQL statement that takes those new rows and puts them into your existing table (thats the transform part of this). You would load the data then use an INSERT . . . SELECT type of statement.

2 - The second way is to write a custom C# program. There are many C# and CSV library to use where you will get an array that contains all of the parts of your source CSV. From there,  you would craft SQL statements that use the CSV parts of the array that correspond to each table field.

Comment: I will be trying the second way that's exactly what I was looking for. I apologize if the question is worded a little confusingly.

Comment: No problem. Once you have the CSV array, its just a matter of writing your SQL statement in the order that your table needs it (and after you modify the data, if needed) and then you execute that SQL statement against your MySQL database. Good luck!

Comment: Yes I feel many query strings in my future! I'll probably be back here soon haha